# Functors which are non-isomorphic but whose derived functors are isomorphic

Tags: category-theory, derived-functors, derived-categories

I was wondering if there is a good/interesting examples of functors that are non-isomorphic as functors but whose derived functors are isomorphic? The example I have encountered so far, the derived Nakayama functor $$\nu = \mathbb{R}\text{Hom}(\text{Hom}(\_,A), K) : \mathcal{D}^b(\text{mod}A) \rightarrow \mathcal{D}^b(\text{mod}A)$$ and the derived functor $$\mathbb{L}(\_ \otimes DA) : \mathcal{D}^b(\text{mod}A) \rightarrow \mathcal{D}^b(\text{mod}A)$$ are isomorphic, but this holds already for the non-derived functors.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: What's the definition of this category?

Comment: It is the bounded derived category of $A$-modules: That means its objects are bounded complexes of $A$-modules (zero for degree $\vert n \vert >> 0$) and the morphisms are given by homotopy classes of chain morphisms where we artificially added inverse morphisms for all quasi-isomorphisms (morphisms that induce isomorphisms on homology), i.e. we localized the quasi-isomorphisms.

Comment: Wouldn't any two exact functors have trivial (and thus isomorphic) derived functors ?

Comment: @Arnaud Did not think of that, but that would indeed be true. Though I'm wondering if there is any examples other than these :)

Comment: @Arnaud I just realised that I think that the homology of the functor on degree zero of a projective resolution (or injective resolution, if left or right) would still be non-isomorphic so they should still be non-isomorphic as functors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical situation when this happens is when you left-derive (for example) a functor $F$ that is not right exact: then its zeroth left derived functor $L_0F$ is actually right exact (in particular, it is not isomorphic to $F$), and the left derived functors for $F$ and $L_0F$ are the same.

(In fact, this is in some sense what always happens (assumig enough projectives etc.): if two functors $F \not\simeq F'$ have $\mathbb{L}F \simeq \mathbb{L}F'$, then at least one of them, say $F$, cannot be right exact, otherwise they are both identified with $L_0F$. Then taking $F$ and $L_0F$ instead of $F, F'$ works too.)

The one example of this that actually comes up is when $F=\widehat{(-)}_I,$ the functor of $I$-adic completion for a finitely generated ideal (over, generally, non-Noetherian ring). In nice cases (when $I$ is "weakly proregular"), $L_0F$ can be described in a nice intrinsic way (it agrees with the so-called "derived $I$-completion"/"analytic $I$-completion").

So, for example, when $I=(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is generated by a regular sequence, the two functors that share their derived functor are the classical $I$-completion $M\mapsto \varprojlim_k M/I^kM$ and the "derived $I$-completion", described by $$M \mapsto M[[X_1, \dots, X_n]]/(X_1-x_1, \dots, X_n-x_n)M[[X_1, \dots, X_n]].$$